# Error running Sharp inside AWS Lambda function: darwin-x64' binaries cannot be used on the 'linux-x64' platform

Tags: aws-lambda, macos-mojave, sharp

When attempting to run sharp inside an AWS Lambda function, I keep getting the following error:

> darwin-x64' binaries cannot be used on the 'linux-x64' platform.
>   Please remove the 'node_modules/sharp/vendor' directory and run 'npm
>   install'

I deploy my serverless applications with Serverless Framework from my MacBook Pro. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: You need to build in a Linux environment as it is different from a Mac O/S environment.

Comment: I believe you're right. But how do I do that? And why is sharp environment dependent?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do that.  From a Mac O/S environment you may consider installing VirtualBox and then putting a Linux distribution there.  Or, if you've already got an AWS account then you could spin up a small EC2 with Linux.  That would require a dev environment in either environment.  And it appears that Sharp has some native components under the hood.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Kudos to [stdunbar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2933977/stdunbar) for steering me in the right direction.

When installing sharp on MacOS via NPM the normal way (i.e.: `npm i sharp --save`), the installer automatically adds binaries for OS X. But AWS lambda functions run on Linux 2 machines with x64 processors and this is why we get this error.

**To fix you must first uninstall sharp completely and then run:**

```
npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp
```

**Note:**

version 0.25 no longer works with the target flag. This used to work:

```
npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux --target=10.15.0 sharp
```

Then deploy as usual from Serverless Framework with `sls deploy`

**Side Note:**

Sharp is EXTREMELY FAST!!! Before using sharp, I was using another image resizing utility named Jimp. It did the job, but was quite slow. To prevent timeout errors, I had to increase the memory size from 128 to 512 and the timeout from 5 seconds to 30 seconds just to handle a typical 1 megabyte image.

Here is a comparison between the two for resizing a 1.2Mb picture down to 600x400 using the same configuration:

> Jimp -> used 512Mb of memory and AWS billed me for 14300 ms.
>
> Sharp -> used 132 MB of memory and AWS billed me for 800 ms.
>
> **That's more than 14x faster than Jimp!!!**

Comment: I tried this `npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp -save` and deployed with serverless, still get this error.  I am on mac.

Comment: It's not -save, it's --save. And you don't need it. Remember to completely uninstall sharp before running the above command.

Comment: I couldn't get this to build and deploy to CloudFoundry via mac properly.  But, you've got me on the right track.  I used a linux VM to build, and that worked.  Thanks!!!

Comment: this works thank you! Do you know if there's a way to install both the mac AND linux version so that I can test locally too?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Docker like I am and come across this issue.

Most likely your `node_modules` folder is being copied from your host machine into the docker container.

Why? Because your `node_modules` folder downloads modules specific to the architecture of your machine (in my case Mac), when you take these packages and try to run them in the container OS, it causes issues because the binaries are for mac (darwin-x64) and it tries to run them on linux (linux-x64) inside the container

To fix it, create a file named `.dockerignore` in the same directory as your `Dockerfile` and update it accordingly.

`.dockerignore`

```
node_modules/
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN ["npm", "install"]
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

It will now ignore the `node_modules` folder on the host machine, and re-populate the modules once command `npm install` inside the Dockerfile has run.

Answer (score 4):

I found an easier solution when building from MacOS or Windows, I use a Makefile with SAM and provide linux as a target for the NPM install.

**template.yaml**

```
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: mycode/
      Handler: handler.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 5
      Role: !GetAtt EdgeLambdaRole.Arn
    Metadata:
        BuildMethod: makefile
```

**mycode/makefile**

```
build-MyFunction:
    cp *.js $(ARTIFACTS_DIR)
    cp package.json $(ARTIFACTS_DIR)
    cp package-lock.json $(ARTIFACTS_DIR)
    cd $(ARTIFACTS_DIR) && npm install --production --arch=x64 --platform=linux
```

*Make sure you use TABS in your makefile*

Answer (score 3):

If you like to `yarn`, set via environment variables

NOTE: I clean up the existing platform/arch first.

```sh
# For macOS/Windows, we can install natively
yarn remove sharp
yarn add sharp

# For AWS Lambda, we need to specify this when we package:
yarn remove sharp
npm_config_platform=linux npm_config_arch=x64 yarn add sharp
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, when i do `npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp` in CMD in windows machine.

Fixed it by opening the CMD in Administrator mode, i did not find any error in running `npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp`

Comment: This fixed my issue where I was getting the error below when I ran 'amplify push': 
npm ERR! path ...\amplify\backend\function\AmplifyFunction\src\node_modules\.bin\semver.cmd
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! File exists: ...\amplify\backend\function\AmplifyFunction\src\node_modules\.bin\semver.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [serverless](https://www.serverless.com) along with [serverless-webpack](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-webpack), you must use this [custom-config](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-webpack#custom-scripts) in your `serverless.yml` file:

```yaml
custom:
  # ...
  webpack:
    # ...
    packagerOptions:
      scripts:
        - npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use SAM you could build your function inside an AWS Lambda-like Linux Docker container:

```
sam build -u
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this post now. I've accomplished this by copying my `package.json` file into an [AWS Cloud9 IDE](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/) and simply running `npm install`. From there, just download the `node_modules/` folder.