# Error: darwin-x64' binaries cannot be used on the 'linux-x64' platform (AWS lambda + typescript + webpack sharp module )

Tags: node.js, webpack, aws-lambda, sharp

aws lambda with typescript is occured error when bundle by webpack.

Before bundle webpack, I did "npm i --arch=x64 --platform=linux --target=12.14.1 sharp" and labmda is working properly.

But, lambda upload zip size is more and more larger.

so, I want to resize lambda upload zip size using serverless-webpack.

Image lambda is working well except using sharp module.

I don't know how to do.

**I did**:

1. Delete node_modules and package-lock.json and install dependencies ( also installed sharp )
2. Delete node_modules/sharp and install sharp ( lambda environment - linux, x64, node version )
3. Set serverless-webpack configuration in serverless
   : packagerOptions ( scrips ) - rebuild sharp lambda enviroment

But, lambda is not working properly.

and I looked many informations.

[lambda linux env]
[Error running Sharp inside AWS Lambda function: darwin-x64' binaries cannot be used on the 'linux-x64' platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60181138/error-running-sharp-inside-aws-lambda-function-darwin-x64-binaries-cannot-be-u)
[Serverless-webpack]
https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack/issues/396

Thank you!

---

[Edit]

My local env : Mac

production env : linux

Maybe, I think that npm command with "--platform" is not working in mac.

Additionally, I solved this problem using aws codebuild.

I posted answer.

But, It is not working in my local [ Mac ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem using aws codebuild.

codebuild has linux and node.js runtime.

So, I ran below command in aws codebuild ( https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install )

```
rm -rf node_modules/sharp
npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp
```

sharp module works properly.

Comment: Many answers tell "using serverless.yml". But, it is not working properly.
Refer to sharp github issue (https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2230)

Answer (score 8):

I got it working by telling webpack to reinstall the package after it runs npm install:

```
webpack:
  includeModules:
    forceExclude:
      - aws-sdk
  packagerOptions:
    scripts:
      - rm -rf node_modules/sharp
      - npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp
```

Comment: when doing that it adds sharp to the all the functions. Did you find anyway that make it bundle to only the function using sharp?

Comment: @AecioLevy Fortunately for me, and unfortunately for you, in my particular case I only have one function. But this GitHub issue implies there's not an easy way without rewriting a bunch of your serverless code: https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack/issues/525

Comment: thank you so much. I end up doing this ``` - if [ -f "api/resize.js" ]; then rm -rf node_modules/sharp && npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp; fi``` but serverless component seems to a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

Dave Cowart's answer helped me a lot but having multiple lambda functions in the repo, I didn't want to install sharp into all of my functions.

Here's my solution:

`serverless.yml`

```
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: 'webpack.config.js'
    includeModules:
      forceExclude:
        - aws-sdk
    packagerOptions:
      scripts:
        - rm -rf node_modules/sharp
        - npm install --production --arch=x64 --platform=linux
```

You don't actually need to specify sharp in the install script. Making it a generic npm install means it will only reinstall sharp if it's in the package.json (which it won't be if it's not used due to webpack tree shaking).

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by using sam cli to build using this command

```
sam build -u
```

This command builds the code inside a container that has the similar environments as lambda